# Problems with ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, http

I wrote an ajax function named getContent() and structured like this

getContent(whichcontent){//code here to get content}

The specific code is here:

```
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    return new XMLHttpRequest(); //Not IE
  } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //IE
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support the XmlHttpRequest object.  Better upgrade to Firefox.");
  }
}

var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

var page_id = 1;

function getContent(which_page,append){
  if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {    

    receiveReq.open("GET", 'spt/page_'+which_page, true);//get the text file

    receiveReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
        handleGetContent(which_page,append);
    }
    receiveReq.send(null);
  }     
}

function handleGetContent(which_page,append){
    if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {        
        if(append == 1){
            $('#container').append("<div class='page' id='page_"+which_page+"'><div class='title'>围城</div><p>" + receiveReq.responseText + "</p><div class='pagenum'>"+which_page+"</div></div>");

        }
        if(append == 0){
          $('#container').prepend("<div class='page' id='page_"+which_page+"'><div class='title'>围城</div><p>" + receiveReq.responseText + "</p><div class='pagenum'>"+which_page+"</div></div>");          
        }
    }
}
```

And I used the getContent like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    getContent(1,1);
    getContent(2,1);
}
```

The problem is I only get one ... and the other one with id page_2 doesn't appear. I'm wondering whether the ajax function can be only called once in a js function or I just made the ajax function wrong. Somebody help me!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `XMLHttpRequest` if you are using `jQuery`? Why don't you use jQuery.ajax from jQuery library http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If your going to use jQuery, you might as well use the `ajax()` function built into it. It's soooo much easier to use and you don't have to worry about that big blob at the start of your code. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: As @ArunPJohny said why you use XML request with Jquery? O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code is ok but if you have doubt with ajax then you can use `jquery` for it, if not then you can a single function for ajax for example: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Or try this code

```
// change the function like
function getContent(which_page,append){
    var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();// Create object here

    receiveReq.open("GET", 'spt/page_'+which_page+'.txt', true);//get the text file
    //write the extension of the file
    receiveReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {    
            handleGetContent(receiveReq,which_page,append);
        }

    }    
    receiveReq.send(null); 
}
// add an extra parameter in this function
function handleGetContent(receiveReq,which_page,append){
    if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {        
        if(append == 1){
            $('#container').append("<div class='page' id='page_"+which_page+"'><div class='title'>围城</div><p>" + receiveReq.responseText + "</p><div class='pagenum'>"+which_page+"</div></div>");

        }
        if(append == 0){
          $('#container').prepend("<div class='page' id='page_"+which_page+"'><div class='title'>围城</div><p>" + receiveReq.responseText + "</p><div class='pagenum'>"+which_page+"</div></div>");          
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function (){
    getContent(1,1);
    getContent(2,1);
});// change this line also
```

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest calls are asyncronous, so if you use only one request object the second call to `getContent` will be ignored because `receiveReq.readyState` is neither 0 nor 4.